# Dragged circles lagging behind cursor in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a program where 2 circles are dragged in a pane. There is also a line connecting them and the distance displayed above it. My problem lies when I drag the circles at a slow pace with the mouse they move fine, but when I move it more quickly the circles stop.

here is where the circle drag is calculated

```
pane.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
        if (circle1.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
            pane.getChildren().clear();
            circle1.setCenterX(e.getX());
            circle1.setCenterY(e.getY());
            pane.getChildren().addAll(getLine(circle1, circle2), circle1,
                circle2, getText(circle1, circle2));
        }
        else if (circle2.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
            pane.getChildren().clear();
            circle2.setCenterX(e.getX());
            circle2.setCenterY(e.getY());
            pane.getChildren().addAll(getLine(circle1, circle2), circle1,
                circle2, getText(circle1, circle2));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

I think what is happening is that when the mouse moves quickly, the distance moved between processing two consecutive events takes it outside the bounds of the circle, so the if condition becomes false. You probably need to register the mouse handlers on the circles themselves, instead of the pane. (As an aside, why clear and rebuild the pane, instead of just update the line?)

Here's an example using these techniques:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DraggingCircles extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Circle circle1 = createDraggingCircle(50, 50, 25, Color.BLUE);
        Circle circle2 = createDraggingCircle(350, 350, 25, Color.RED);
        Line line = new Line();
        line.startXProperty().bind(circle1.centerXProperty());
        line.startYProperty().bind(circle1.centerYProperty());
        line.endXProperty().bind(circle2.centerXProperty());
        line.endYProperty().bind(circle2.centerYProperty());
        pane.getChildren().addAll(circle1, circle2, line);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Circle createDraggingCircle(double x, double y, double radius, Color fill) {
        Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, radius, fill);
        ObjectProperty<Point2D> mouseLocation = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        circle.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            mouseLocation.set(new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY()));
        });

        circle.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            double deltaX = e.getX() - mouseLocation.get().getX();
            double deltaY = e.getY() - mouseLocation.get().getY();
            circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() + deltaX);
            circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY() + deltaY);
            mouseLocation.set(new Point2D(e.getX(), e.getY()));
        });

        return circle ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```